# wifi randomly disconnects windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

My wifi keeps disconnecting. I think it's my computer because my other devices still work. I already checked my wifi drivers and it says they are all up to date. I changed my wifi adapter from device manager to never go to low power mode. And then I restarted.

When I go to wifi in task manager, it is usually around 200 Kbps receive, but then it randomly dips to 4-40 Kbps, then spikes back up. So it doesn't actually disconnect, just becomes really slow. I am in a call right now and when it dips I disconnect from the call.
The 200 Kbps is just because I'm not doing much right now. If I try downloading something, it goes up to a few Mbps.

I just updated windows 10 maybe a month ago.

Comment: Assuming you have bluetooth functionality on the computer, does the problem still occur if you disable bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

In order to check to see if there are any software issues, you can try a few of the things outlined in Microsoft's webpage on [how to fix WiFi problems on Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-wi-fi-connection-issues-in-windows-9424a1f7-6a3b-65a6-4d78-7f07eee84d2c).

A few things to check in order to narrow down the source, is to check what happens when you attempt to connect to different WiFi networks. Does this only happen on the specific network you're connecting to or does it happen for any connection?

If it's only a problem on your main WiFi network, then the following steps may help:

1. Try moving the computer around, mainly closer to the router you are connecting to to make sure there aren't any connection issues, possibly connect it to Ethernet to test if this solves your problems
2. Run the Network troubleshooter by going to Start → Settings → Network and Internet → Status → Network Troubleshooter (close to the bottom of the status page)
3. If you have access to a 2.4GHz WiFi band and a 5GHz band (Ie. For 5GHz, it'll normally say Wifi_5G compared to Wifi), attempt to connect to the other one
4. If none of the previous work. Try opening Command Prompt and type the following commands:

   - `netsh winsock reset`
   - `netsh int ip reset`
   - `ipconfig /release`
   - `ipconfig /renew`
   - `ipconfig /flushdns`

If this occurs on all networks, then it's likely a problem with the machine rather than your connection to the network. You can try the following steps as well:

1. Run the network troubleshooter outlined in step 2 of the previous section
2. Try uninstalling the network adapter and restart the computer to reinstall it (you will need to be admin for this)

   - Go to start and type Device Manager
   - Expand Network adapters and find the driver. This will be something like Intel Wireless-AC (R)
   - Right click and click uninstall device. If you're prompted, press the Delete the device software for this device and then Uninstall
   - Restart computer
3. As noted by @Tim_Stewart in the comments, you can also install the specific driver for your model by uninstalling the current driver and reinstalling one from the manufacturers site by searching "<Model number> Drivers" (note you should download the driver **before** you uninstall)

If none of this works, then your alternative may be to do a full network reset however note that any networking you've done with VPNs, etc, will also be reset using the following steps

1. Go to Start → Settings → Network and Internet → Status → Network reset
2. On the network reset screen, select Reset Now and then Yes and wait for the computer to restart

Hopefully the previous steps can help out, these were mostly derived from the steps in the link I sent before so for further clarification regarding steps, that may help out

Comment: isn't uninstalling the device the same as just clicking "update driver"

Comment: If your wifi driver is installed incorrectly but is the latest version, when you click Update, nothing will happen I believe as Windows will report that it's already the latest version. Whereas uninstall will ensure that if the wifi driver wasn't installed properly, it will attempt to try again correctly

Comment: This is a decent answer . The only thing I would add is to try totally uninstalling the drivers, and making sure to reinstall with **the latest manufacturer drivers**. I know it's convenient to let windows try and find them, but they aren't the greatest choice for alot of popular cards. +1 from me

Comment: Also, welcome to superuser!

Comment: I don't have another network to try to connect to, but I tried uninstalling the device and restarting. The device was automatically reinstalled but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Assuming the answer that Anant-Tiwari suggested didn't help fix your problem, your best bet may install the drivers using the manufacturers site as Tim said. To do this, find the model number for your computer and then search for the drivers specific to your model. There should be some form of internet driver that you can download and install -to attempt to fix it. Alternatively, there may be some hardware fault considering other the devices work properly

Answer (score 0):

In my case, windows automatically turned off the network adapter to save power. Go to **Device Manager (as an Admin) > Expand "Network Adapters" > Right click your adapter > Properties > Change Settings > Power Management > Uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"**. This might fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue (all devices work flawlessly, one older laptop either randomly disconnects, either never connects from boot) when both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz broadcast shared same network name.
The malfunctioning device could not connect to 5 GHz at all. i.e. solution was to have different network names for different freqs.